# Server error (500) when attempting to post a transaction from Brownie + ApeSafe

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I post transaction every other day, to multiple Safes using a combination of Brownie and the legacy [ape-safe](https://safe.ape.tax/) (I know, upgrade is due). Since yesterday, attempting to post to Ethereum Mainnet and Arbitrum safes fails with the following error:

```
ApiError: Error posting transaction:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Server Error (500)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Server Error (500)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Did anything break/change on the server side? Services seem to be [up](https://status.safe.global/history/safe-tx-service-mainnet).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Issue was found and [fix](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-transaction-service/pull/1736) was pushed. Confirmed proper functioning.